# UIScrollView contentSize gets reset

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

I need to add textfields to a scrollview dynamically. Im able to do it, after adding I do calculate and update the content size  of the scrollview every time.

After updating the content size I'm able to view it on screen, once I edit the textfield (keyboard disappears) I content size to reset to original value. Am I missing out something here? The scroll view is created through xib.

Comment: Whats the issue, screenshots and code would help.

Comment: post your code which is placed in text filed delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the last textFiled's y position.

Now use below line after all textFields are added to ScrollView.

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, yPos)];
```

and for keyboard issue user the below code.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

[textField resignFirstResponder];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, yPos)];
return YES;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
    {
        self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 240);// set height of self.scrollView.frame, as you need.
        return YES;
    }

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
   {

        [self.txtFieldName resignFirstResponder];
        .
        ,
        .

        self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460); // set height of self.scrollView.frame, as you need.
        [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 465)]; // set height of self.scrollView.ContentSize, as you need.

        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: PLease have a look at this sample http://tbf.me/a/9llOl .  Please try editing fields before adding a new field and after adding new field

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` Method,

```
y = 500; // As you wish

scrMain.delegate = self;
scrMain.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, y);
```

Then, For textfield entry

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    scrMain.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, y + 50);
}
```

After return key,

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    scrMain.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, y);
    return YES;
 }
```

Comment: I did retain the new content size in a class variable and then reset it when keyboard returns.
This unfortunately coincides with the view shift code(code which shifts the view up when keyboard appears, just to bring the textfield to visible region). 

The mere call of [mScrollView setContentSize:mScrollContentSize]; is upsetting my whole lot of other functionalities. 

I don't understand why the content size should reset, when the keyboard appears and disappears. 

Im lost on this!

Comment: Just thought will post the solution. This had something to do with auto layout. unchecking the auto layout fixed half the problem and Apple's keyboard programming guide fixed the other half. There is one think I would mention(if it helps), The keyboard size is always returned in portrait mode even when the app is in landscape. Also once the auto layout is turned off, the contentSize of the scroll is to be set manually in the viewDidAppear method

Comment: The keyboard size is always returned in portrait mode even when the app is in landscape. -> not getting with this.

Comment: My application supports only landscape mode. I had to scroll the scrollview to bring textfield to visible region. I copied the keyboardWasShown function from Apple's keyboard programming guide which used the keyboard size to scroll up the text field. I had to set the width to height and height to width for landscape mode to make it work.    keyboardSize = CGSizeMake(keyboardSize.height, keyboardSize.width);